# Error al insertar en base de datos de WordPress código embebido de Google Maps usando preg_match()

Tags: wordpress, preg-match

Estoy intentando insertar el código embebido de Google Map, pero en el momento de la inserción quiero usar `preg_match()` para solo guardar el ma base de datos la url.

El objetivo es facilitarle la vida al cliente y que no tenga que copiar la url, sino que pueda pegar todo el código y encargarme yo de limpiar el asunto e insertar en la base de datos solamente la url...

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
if ( $_POST['google_map'] ) :
    $code = $_POST['google_map'];
    $pattern = '/src=["\']?([^"\' ]*)["\' ]/is';
    preg_match( $pattern, $code, $match );
    if ( $match ) :
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'google_map', trim( urldecode( $match[1] ) ) );
    endif;
endif;
?>
```

Pero sencillamente no pasa nada, inserta un campo vacío. Sin embargo hago una simulación en un archivo `.php` normal y funciona como espero.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ten cuidado con los caracteres especiales, debes escaparlos. WP tiene funciones para ello. Intenta algo así: `$url=esc_url_raw( trim(urldecode($match[1])) );` y luego: `$upm=update_post_meta( $post_id, 'google_map', $url );`  Haz una prueba y dinos qué devuelve: `var_dump($upm);`

Comment: Gracias por responder. Lamentablemente el resultado sigue siendo el mismo, inserta el campo pero vacío... Sigo intentando.